# Java Run Time Critical Error

Tags: java, applet, runtime-error

I'm having run time error,

when i running java app on my web site,

I'm using applet for make my Java App be available on the Web Page and everything seems to be right:

I tried a lot of things but error still there

When i load an app i got the following message on the Java console:

```
 --> Critical Error: This client key (#***-***-****) expired on 12/2012.
```

What changes of my web application can influence my Java App,

Any idea why it happening?

Comment: Can you provide some more info? A Java Applet doesn't (necessarily) interacts with a web app, so I don't see any reason for a change in your web app influence on that. If you could describe your architecture with a little more detail.

Comment: i think it´s kind of error refers to the licence of Java Usage.

Comment: Which version of Java from which vendor? Oracle's Java does not require a license. Did you write the Java app yourself? If not, ask the person or company who wrote the app.

Comment: If you use a signed Applet to access the client's machine resources then there would be a key that the client should accept. That is why I am asking for more details